# Switching image on hover in a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change an image that is placed in a button on hover. So far, I have managed for the image itself to change when you hover over it but not for when the button itself is hovered. Here is the code.

```
    <style>
    .btn-large{
        width: 300px;
        height: 350px;
    }
    .movie{
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    #hardware:hover, #hardware:active{
        background: #23c6c8;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large" id="hardware">
            <figure>
                <img class="movie" alt="ticket" src="http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/BuK26gd.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png'" />
            </figure>
                <div class="details">
                    <h2>All Tickets</h2></br>
                    <p>View all tickets</p>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the button img?

Comment: to accept an answer, hover beside the answer in question and click the tick that appears beside it. It means 15 points for the answerer and you get a badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move the event handlers to the anchor instead of the `img` and search for the img tag

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/YXJyyp?editors=101)**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large" id="hardware"
   onmouseover="this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src ='http://i.imgur.com/BuK26gd.png'" 
   onmouseout="this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png'">
  <figure>
    <img class="movie" alt="ticket" src="http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png"  />
  </figure>
  <div class="details">
    <h2>All Tickets</h2></br>
    <p>View all tickets</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I did try moving the event handlers to the 'a' tag but couldn't get the right results. I guess I need to learn more javacript.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .btn-large {
      width: 300px;
      height: 350px;
    }
    .details {
      background: url("http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png") no-repeat;
      height: 90px;
    }
    .details:hover,
    .details:active {
      background: url("http://i.imgur.com/BuK26gd.png") no-repeat;
    }
    figure {
      height: 90px;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large" id="hardware">
  <div class="details">
    <figure>
      &nbsp;
    </figure>
    <h2>All Tickets</h2>
    </br>
    <p>View all tickets</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Quite simple - just add css for `details` and `figure` to your stylesheet and set a background image and a different one on hover. You can remove the alternating imgs from your html

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/povseyw5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
<style>
.btn-large{
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
}

.image{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/u8wsfFL.png");
}

.btn-large:hover .image{
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/BuK26gd.png");
}

.btn-large:hover .details{
    background: #23c6c8;
    color: red;
}
</style>



<div class="btn-large">

        <div class="image">           
        </div>

        <div class="details">
             <h2>All Tickets</h2></br>
             <p>View all tickets</p>
        </div>

</div>
```